# i3 window manager: black screen, no mouse

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, i3

I installed i3-gaps on my arch running with a nvidia card. A gnome-session works fine using the nvidia.

After the installation i added to the xinitrc file:

```
exec i3
```

however when I execute `startx` in a tty, the X Server starts successfully, but i3 shows nothing else but black screen (no shortcuts are working)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late to answer this, but just in case someone stumble upon this,
it was doing the same thing to me but it worked using `xinit` instead of `startx`